# Efficient Binary Serialization Of Mostly Basic Types

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for transferring some data over the network. Here is what i'm hoping to achieve:

The application runs and computes some data:

```
int w = 5;
float x = 4.736;
std::string y = "Some String.";
std::vector<int> z;
z.push_back(1);
z.push_back(2);
z.push_back(3);
```

Then we put it in a binary container:

```
BinaryContainer Data;
Data.Write(w);
Data.Write(x);
Data.Write(y);
Data.Write(z);
```

We then transfer it over the network:

```
SendData(Data.c_str());
```

And read it out on the other side:

```
BinaryContainer ReceivedData(IncomingData);
int w = ReceivedData.Read();
float x = ReceivedData.Read();
std::string y = ReceivedData.Read();
std::vector<int> z = ReceivedData.Read();
```

The example above outlines how the basic functionality from a high level perspective should work. I've looked at many different serialization libraries and none seem to fit quite right. I'm leaning towards learning how to write the functionality myself.

Endianness doesn't matter. The architecture that reads and writes data will never differ.
We only need to store binary data inside the container. The reading application and writing application is exclusively responsible for reading data in the same order it was written. Only basic types need to be written, no entire arbitrary classes or pointers to things. Most importantly overall the speed in which this occurs should be of the highest priority because once the data is formulated, we need to write it to the container, transfer it over the network, and read it on the other end as fast as possible.

Network transmission is currently being done using the low level WinSock RIO API and we're moving data from the application to the wire as fast as possible already. Transmission latency across the wire will always be a much higher and variable rate. The point at which we serialize our data before transmission is the next step in the chain to ensure we are wasting as little time as possible before getting our data out on the wire.

New packets will be received very quickly, and as such the ability to preallocate resources would be beneficial. For example:

```
Serializer DataHandler;
...
void NewIncomingPacket(const char* Data)
{
    DataHandler.Reset();
    DataHandler.Load(Data);
    int x = DataHandler.Read();
    float y = DataHandler.Read();
    ...
}
```

I'm looking for input from community experts on which direction to go here.

Comment: "none seem to fit quite right" what isn't quite fit in those libraries that you're trying to solve by creating your own library/functionality? We can try to avoid those solutions in the answers.

Comment: I'd suggest using protobuff. It is simple, super-fast, works out of box and has implementations for many languages and is binary

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/)? Why it does not suit your needs? Live demo for serialization of your objects is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8nLet1NhoeQosFWW).

Comment: Can you explain how [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) "do not seem to fit quite right"?

Comment: Regarding performance I suspect the real bottleneck will be network throughput -- *not* time taken to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I do not want to use boost. Any serialization library I found that requires a predefined schema does not fit with my needs. When comparing benchmarks, the YAS library is extremely fast but doesnt appear to support reading and writing data to a single buffer in small chunks, Cereal does allow this but is an order of magnitude slower than YAS. It would seem like writing my own bare bones library to handle this would allow me to get the functionality i require without any extra bloat and ensure it is as fast as possible.

Comment: If you don't care about endianness and all types are trivial (all builtin types are) then you're fine with a `memcpy(buffer, vector.data(), vector.data() + vector.size())` and similar for deserialization. It's the fastest and safe option given your scenario.

Comment: @Sopel `memcpy` as a third argument takes a number of bytes to be copied, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about endianness and only want to serialize trivial types than a simple memcpy will be the fastest and also safe. Just memcpy into/out of the buffer when serializing/deserializing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t CapacityV>
struct BinaryContainer
{
    BinaryContainer() :
        m_write(0),
        m_read(0)
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    void write(const std::vector<T>& vec)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);

        // TODO: check if access is valid

        const std::size_t bytes = vec.size() * sizeof(T);
        std::memcpy(m_buffer + m_write, vec.data(), bytes);
        m_write += bytes;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void write(T value)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);

        // TODO: check if access is valid

        const std::size_t bytes = sizeof(T);
        std::memcpy(m_buffer + m_write, &value, bytes);
        m_write += bytes;
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> read(std::size_t count)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);

        // TODO: check if access is valid

        std::vector<T> result;
        result.resize(count);

        const std::size_t bytes = count * sizeof(T);
        std::memcpy(result.data(), m_buffer + m_read, bytes);
        m_read += bytes;

        return result;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T read()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<T>);

        // TODO: check if access is valid

        T result;

        const std::size_t bytes = sizeof(T);
        std::memcpy(&result, m_buffer + m_read, bytes);
        m_read += bytes;

        return result;
    }

    const char* data() const
    {
        return m_buffer;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return m_write;
    }

private:
    std::size_t m_write;
    std::size_t m_read;
    char m_buffer[CapacityV]; // or a dynamically sized equivalent
};

int main()
{

    BinaryContainer<1024> cont;

    {
        std::vector<std::uint32_t> values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        // probably want to make serializing size part of the vector serializer
        cont.write(values.size());
        cont.write(values);
    }

    {
        auto size = cont.read<std::vector<std::uint32_t>::size_type>();
        auto values = cont.read<std::uint32_t>(size);

        for (auto val : values) std::cout << val << ' ';
    }
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d176a41666dbad1

Comment: At a first glance this appears to be exactly what I was looking for. A specialized `WriteVector()`/`ReadVector()` can be added to make it simpler to use. I assume other array types like `std::map` can be easily added in a similar fashion if needed?

Comment: arrays, yes. For maps you would need to serialize each key, entry pair separately since the memory is not contiguous. But the interface can be the same for any type.

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Can you elaborate on the `check if access is valid` comments? Is this so we don't try writing past the end of the buffer?

Comment: yes, and also not read past the `write` pointer. But that's up to your needs, it may be unnecessary or only important for debug builds

Comment: I'm having an issue reading and writing `const char*`. After transmission, the receiver is unable to `read<const char*`>()`. If I `write` and subsequently `read` a `const char*` from within the same application instance it works fine. I believe this is because we are serializing the pointer and not the value behind it?

Comment: "I believe this is because we are serializing the pointer and not the value behind it?" Yes. Do you want to serialize graph-like (or tree-like) non-contiguous structures, or a string pointed to by the char*? In the first case it's complex and there are libraries for it. In the second case you need to create an overload that takes a pointer and some size.

Comment: I intended for `write<const char*>()` to send text.

Comment: So you really want to send an array of chars. Just memcpy all the chars to the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I've written [seriously](https://github.com/panta/seriously), an header-only fast C++ library that should do what you want :-)

It provides both a serializer and a de-serializer.

Serialized data is portable across different architectures and endianness. No external dependencies.

```cpp
    seriously::Packer<1024> packer;     // a 1024 byte serialization buffer

    int32_t value1 = 83656;
    bool value2 = true;
    int16_t value3 = -2345;
    std::string value4("only an example");
    double value5 = -6.736;
    std::vector<int64_t> value6;

    value6.push_back(42);
    value6.push_back(11);
    value6.push_back(93);

    packer << value1 << value2 << value3 << value4 << value5 << value6;

    std::cout << "packed size: " << packer.size() << std::endl;
    // packer.data() contains the serialized data

    int32_t restored1;
    bool restored2;
    int16_t restored3;
    std::string restored4;
    double restored5 = -6.736;
    std::vector<int64_t> restored6;

    packer >> restored1 >> restored2 >> restored3 >> restored4 >> restored5 >> restored6;

    std::cout << "unpacked: " << restored1 << " " << (restored2 ? "t" : "f") << " " << restored3 << " " << restored4 << " " << restored5 << std::endl;

    std::vector<int64_t>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = restored6.begin(); it != restored6.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like I will need to create a new `seriously::Packer` every time a new packet arrives, is there much overhead from this?

Comment: Note that OP wants to serialize a vector. Your library does not seem to support that.

Comment: @KKlouzal Are you sure you are fine with a buffer of a static (compile-time-defined) size? I would quite hesitate to use this approach in production code. What if the sent data will not fit into?

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica yes, but I think that would be useful in general, so probably I could add that

Comment: A single packet will never be larger than a predefined size, so that's not a problem. Not being able to serialize a vector isn't a huge deal but an inconvenience nonetheless.

Comment: @KKlouzal the overhead is minimal, but in any case there is no need to create a new one, just call `.rewind()` and it is as freshly instantiated. I'll add the support for `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Handling endianness is a lot of overhead compared to a simple memcpy.

Comment: @KKlouzal I've pushed the updated library with support for float, double and std::vector<T>

Comment: @Sopel if there is network communication involved, that overhead is probably negligible. It's a question of tradeoffs, and I need portability, but of course YMMV.

Comment: if it's a fast local network it may not. OP said he wants it to be fast. I'm not saying it won't be fast enough for his needs. Just stating that's it is significant overhead compared to memcpy.

Comment: @Sopel on my i7 htonll() / ntohll() process ~44 Gbit/s. So it starts to become significant when using (at full speed) a 10Gbit/s network (with saturated 100Gbit/s it's of course very significant)

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni you're right actually, I forgot about `bswap` instruction on x86 and it's indeed very fast.